# How to integrate google tests into TFS 2010 Build?

Tags: tfsbuild, googletest

We are using googletest http://code.google.com/p/googletest/ to make our C++ unit tests and we need to integrate googletest in our TFS 2010 build server. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do if  googletest supports commandline execution